# Can't debug Angular-cli 1.1.1 output in browser

Tags: angular

In my project I'm running ng test -> clicking DEBUG -> opening sources in developer tools -> hitting cmd+p -> and can't find my *.ts sources anymore.
It worked last week before the update to 1.1.1. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Angular cli. Should be fixed soon.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6640